# How to troubleshoot problems with snapshot creation

Tags: snapshot, erp, acumatica

I'm creating a snapshot of an Acumatica company instance, when I begin the snapshot process it works for a while and gives me an error "An error occurred while importing data into 'Name' table."

How could I troubleshoot what's wrong in said table?

What are some common errors that could trigger this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Was the snapshot prepared with the same version of Acumatica that you're trying to restore it with? Which version is it? Can you go to Help->Trace and print the full stack trace?

Comment: The trace shows this:

Error: 
68: An error occurred while importing data into 'EmpTaxUntaxAccumHist' table. 

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required. 
Parameter name: count 
  at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count) 
  at PX.BulkInsert.BinaryDataReader.ParseBinary(ColumnInfo fi) 
  at PX.BulkInsert.BinaryDataReader.ReadColumn(ColumnInfo fi) 
  at PX.BulkInsert.DataImport.ReadRow(IBulkDataReader reader) 
  at PX.BulkInsert.DataImport.Read(IBulkDataReader reader)

Comment: at PX.BulkInsert.DataImport.InternalStart(IBulkDataReader reader) 
  at PX.BulkInsert.BaseDataProcessor`1.PrepareStart(DataHandler handler) 
  at PX.BulkInsert.BaseDataProcessor`1.Start(DataHandler handler) 
  at PX.BulkInsert.BaseDataProcessor`1.Start(Stream stream) 
  at PX.Data.Update.PXSnapshotUploader.CreateSnapshot(ZipArchive zip) 
  at PX.Data.Update.PXSnapshotUploader.CreateSnapshot(ZipArchive zip) 
  at PX.Data.Update.DatabaseLock.DatabaseOperation(PXDatabaseProvider provider, Action act, Boolean lockDB)

Comment: at PX.Data.Update.PXSnapshotUploader.InternalStart() 
  at PX.Data.Update.PXSnapshotBase.Start() 
  at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4()

Answer (score 0):

You just have to publish construction feature, construction report and construction dashboards package 
**package version and snapshot version should be same Version.**

Answer (score -1):

Basically you need to have equal structure in your database like.
So, i can recommend
1. get a snapshot without customization
2. get published customization project
3. apply client customization on your local site
4. upload snapshot and restore